# Consecutive Coin Count

Tags: python-3.x

Program runs and stops after conditions are met. I need the program to stop after 3 consecutive heads are flipped. How can this be done?

```
import random

def flips():
    """Coin flip simulation."""

    # sum of coins
    sum_heads = 0
    sum_tails = 0

    # Simulation
    while True:
        coin = random.randint(0,1)
        if coin == 0:
            print("heads")
            sum_heads += 1
        else:
            print("tails")
            sum_tails += 1
        if sum_heads == 8:
            print("Simulation complete! 8 total heads were flipped.")
            break
        if sum_tails == 9:
            print("Simulation complete! 9 total tails were flipped.")
            break

    # Ask user for repeat    
    result = input("Would you like to run the simulation again (yes/no)? ").lower()
    while result == "yes":
        flips()
        break
flips()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a counter for consecutive heads that turns back to 0 in case the next is tail.

```
def flips():
    """Coin flip simulation."""

    # sum of coins
    sum_heads = 0
    sum_tails = 0
    consecutive = 0
    # Simulation
    while True:
        coin = random.randint(0,1)
        if coin == 0:
            print("heads")
            consecutive+=1
            if consecutive==3:
                print("Simulation complete! 3 consecutive heads were flipped.")
                break
            sum_heads += 1
        else:
            consecutive = 0
            print("tails")
            sum_tails += 1
        if sum_heads == 8:
            print("Simulation complete! 8 total heads were flipped.")
            break
        if sum_tails == 9:
            print("Simulation complete! 9 total tails were flipped.")
            break

    # Ask user for repeat    
    result = input("Would you like to run the simulation again (yes/no)? ").lower()
    while result == "yes":
        flips()
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to keep it as simple as possible. You can try this.

```
import random

def flips():
        """Coin flip simulation."""

    # sum of coins
    sum_heads = 0
    sum_tails = 0

    last_3_results = []

    # Simulation
    while True:
        coin = random.randint(0,1)
        if coin == 0:
            sum_heads += 1
            print("heads")
        else:
            print("tails")
            sum_tails += 1
        if sum_heads == 8:
            print("Simulation complete! 8 total heads were flipped.")
            break
        if sum_tails == 9:
            print("Simulation complete! 9 total tails were flipped.")
            break

        last_3_results.append(coin)

        if len(last_3_results) > 3:
            last_3_results.pop(0)

        if len(last_3_results) ==3 and len(set(last_3_results)) == 1 and last_3_results[0] == 0:
            break

    # Ask user for repeat    
    result = input("Would you like to run the simulation again (yes/no)? ").lower()
    while result == "yes":
        flips()
        break
flips()
```